# Flutter agora dependency duplication error in grade

Tags: android, flutter, android-gradle-plugin, agora.io, agora

After implementing agora plugin I am getting this error. if I removed the plugin my code is working well.

[11:01 am, 08/09/2023] Flexsin Avaneesh: Launching lib/stage/main_stage.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleStageDebug'...
error: supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
class io.agora.advancedvideo.externvideosource.ExternalVideoInputManager, unresolved supertypes: io.agora.rtc.mediaio.IVideoSource
Adding -Xextended-compiler-checks argument might provide additional information.

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkStageDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class io…
> [11:01 am, 08/09/2023] Flexsin Avaneesh: Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.internal.AudioRoutingController$ControllerErrorState found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
> Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.internal.AudioRoutingController$ControllerStartState found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
> Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.internal.AudioRoutingController$ControllerState found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
> Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.internal.AudioRoutingController$ControllerStopState found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
> Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.AgoraImage found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
> Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.AgoraVideoFrame found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
> Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.CameraCapturerConfiguration found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
> Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.CameraCapturerConfiguration$CAMERA_DIRECTION found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
> Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.ChannelMediaInfo found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
> Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.ChannelMediaRelayConfiguration found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
> Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.EncodedVideoFrameInfo found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
> Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.IVideoFrameObserver found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
> Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.VideoCanvas found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
> Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.VideoCapture found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
> Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.VideoCapture$AndroidFillLightMode found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
> Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.VideoCapture$AndroidImageFormat found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
> Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.VideoCapture$AndroidMeteringMode found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
> Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.VideoCapture$AndroidVideoCaptureError found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
> Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.VideoCapture$AndroidVideoCaptureFrameDropReason found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
> Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.VideoCapture$FramerateRange found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
> Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.VideoCapture$VideoCaptureApi found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)

```
 Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.VideoCaptureFactory$ChromiumCameraInfo found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
 Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.VideoCaptureFormat found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
 Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.VideoCaptureFormatParser found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
 Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.VideoCaptureScreen found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
 Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.VideoCaptureScreen$1 found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
 Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.VideoCaptureScreen$2 found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
 Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.VideoCaptureScreen$3 found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
 Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.VideoCompositingLayout found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
 Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.VideoCompositingLayout$Builder found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
 Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.VideoCompositingLayout$Canvas found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
 Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.VideoCompositingLayout$Region found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
 Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.VideoEncoderConfiguration found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
 Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.VideoEncoderConfiguration$DEGRADATION_PREFERENCE found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
 Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.VideoEncoderConfiguration$FRAME_RATE found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
 Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.VideoEncoderConfiguration$MIRROR_MODE_TYPE found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
 Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.VideoEncoderConfiguration$ORIENTATION_MODE found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
 Duplicate class io.agora.rtc2.video.VideoEncoderConfiguration$VideoDimensions found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
 Duplicate class io.agora.utils.SqliteWrapper found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)
 Duplicate class io.agora.utils.SqliteWrapper$StorageItem found in modules jetified-agoraplayer-1.2.4-runtime (io.agora:agoraplayer:1.2.4) and jetified-full-sdk-4.2.2-runtime (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.2)

 Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
```

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileStageDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17m 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleStageDebug failed with exit code 1